# How to improve Prototype.js callback function code

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have this small code. I am using the Prototype framework but I am unable to bind elements to the callback function. That's why I have to write the function like this.

How may I improve this code?

```
 Event.observe('firstname', 'keyup', function () {
     var form = $('customerform'),
         firstname_0 = form["firstname_0"];
     firstname.value = this.value;
 });
 Event.observe('KundeNachname', 'keyup', function () {
     var form = $('customerform'),
         lastname_0 = form["lastname_0"];
     lastname_0.value = this.value;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('customerform')['lastname_0'].value = this.value;
```

This condenses your three lines of code into one.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('customerform')['lastname_0'].value = this.value;`?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between each of your callbacks is the name of the form field that's referenced. I'd extract that code into a common callback-creating function:

```
function createHandler(fieldName) {
    return function() {
        $('customerform')[fieldName].value = this.value;
    }
}

Event.observe('firstname', 'keyup', createHandler("firstname_0"));
Event.observe('KundeNachname', 'keyup', createHandler("lastname_0"));
```